# openpyxl not writing to cell?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am not exactly sure why it isn't writing to the sheet? The name is correct and I've been able to read from the workbook. Do I have to close the file in order for changes to be made?

```
 workBookWrite = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
 workSheetWrite = workBookWrite.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet2')
 workSheetWrite.cell(items.get_Pos(),1,items.get_URL())
```

[image: Heres the Execel file]

Comment: You need to save the file. Also, if you have the file open in another application such as MS Excel, you will have to close it.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, use:

`workBookWrite.save(path)`